# Problem with Xtreme Download Manager notification icon

Tags: 13.10, notification, system-tray, downloaders

XDM had been working fine for, but I think the problem arose once I updated it. Instead of the notification icon being in the tray, it now floats on the screen. This is really annoying because it blocks other items on the screen. 
It looks like this,

[image]

How can I fix this glitch? I've already tried completely removing and re-installing, but it does nothing.

Comment: Same problem here, on ubuntu 14.04 it was fine since last time i updated a few software. I've removed them but nothing happend.it's icon is flowing on the screen same as above picture.

Comment: same issue on 15.10

Answer (score 0):

I'have found the problem.
go to the options and unmark show download box in general tap xdman icon will disappear from the desktop and restart the xdman it's icon will go to the taskbar,

but I should say that i removed all of the xdman configurations with these commands before doing the steps above :

```
sudo apt-get remove xdman
```

that will remove the xdman package.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

that will remove all unnecessary packages...packages that were installed but are no longer being used by any other packages. This applies to any packages not being used, not just xdman.

```
sudo apt-get purge xdman
```

or

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xdman
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the post is almost two years old, but since I stumbled upon it, anyone else might as well. So here's the solution:

Right click on the icon to exit XDM. Then run XDM from Dash. Go to Tools -> Options, and uncheck the Show download box option in the General Tab.

By the way, this is only a workaround, and the issue is recurring. I don't know of any foolproof way to get rid of it for good. Reinstalling the software seems a bit of a stretch, though.

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop the Java process from running
2. Open the terminal and run:

   ```
   cd $HOME
   cd .xdman
   rm -f downloads.txt
   ```

I found this to work for me. Here is the link discussion link: [Xtreme Download Manager / Discussion / XDM Bug Report: Debian 9 xdman not open!!!](https://sourceforge.net/p/xdman/discussion/xdmbug/thread/904f38ad/)